# Employer asking to take leave in notice

Tags: resignation, india

What if old employer not accepting resignation and when employee not able to serve notice due to medical and family issues, what if employer without acknowledgement of resignation and asking to take leave in notice period?

Comment: You need to add a nationality / location  to this as laws vary from place to place.

Comment: Your question does not really make a lot of sense in normal western employment context. Is this maybe about India or another rather quirky system?

Answer (score 2):

I'm presuming that this question is from India due to the requirement of a Relieving Letter and if the resignation isn't accepted, such a letter will be denied.

My understanding of Indian law is that there is no legal requirement for such a letter to be issued, but witholding one, although is a semi-common threat, is frowned upon.

In terms of the acceptance of Resignation: [This great Article, presuming that this is India](https://www.ahlawatassociates.com/blog/position-regarding-notice-period-under-the-indian-labour-and-employment-law-regime/#:%7E:text=The%20Apex%20Court%20clarified%20the,or%20disciplinary%20proceedings%20is%20pending) - In short outlines that the Employee always has the right to resign, the Employer can enforce a notice period or demand wages in lieu of a notice period - but ultimately there is no way that an employer can decline to accept a resignation,.

Answer (score 0):

Resignation isn't something that your employer needs to "accept" - it's something that you tell them is happening.

If you're unable to work in your notice period or are asking for leave during that period then that's no different to if you're unable to work during your normal employment - so you need to follow the usual policies laid our by your employer and in your contract.

Comment: Depends on the location: in India you would very much be wrong, for example.

Comment: *"Resignation isn't something that your employer needs to "accept""* - certainly in the past and for staff jobs, it was common enough to *offer* or *ask permission* to resign, rather than simply announcing departure. It's quite possible the OP is in a culture where that is still normal, or a jurisdiction where the employer's consent is actually required (which was true in 19th century Britain, which is probably where India gets the practice from).